# Where clause in generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method that takes 2 generics parameters: BType and IType. Is there a way to define in the method signature that BType has to be a implementation of IType?!?

Edit1: here the method signature:

```
public static Expression<Func<BType, bool>> CastFunc<BType,IType>(Expression<Func<IType, bool>> customWhereClause)
```

Comment: We need more details to help.

Comment: what prevented you from posting the method signature along with the question?

Comment: Note that those are unconventional type parameter names...

Comment: Could you just use a generic type constraint?

Comment: @Jonesy sorry i forgot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static Expression<Func<BType, bool>> CastFunc<BType,IType>(Expression<Func<IType, bool>> customWhereClause) where BType : IType
```

Documentation "Constraints on Type Parameters": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: I marked you as answer because of the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

```
public void Foo<BType, IType>(BType a, IType b) where BType : IType
```